# dkms autoinstallation failed for rtl8188eu on kali linux

Tags: kali-linux

I got error while running apt or dpkg package,

here it's is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 159 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-6.5.0-kali3-amd64 (6.5.6-1kali1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.5.0-kali3-amd64.
The kernel is built without module signing facility, modules won't be signed

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' -j4 KVER=6.5.0-kali3-amd64 KSRC=/lib/modules/6.5.0-kali3-amd64/build..............(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-kali3-amd64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8188eu/5.13.3/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.5.0-kali3-amd64/x86_64 succeeded for 8188eu realtek-rtl8188eus virtualbox
dkms autoinstall on 6.5.0-kali3-amd64/x86_64 failed for rtl8188eu(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
dkms: autoinstall for kernel: 6.5.0-kali3-amd64 failed!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.5.0-kali3-amd64 (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.5.0-kali3-amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up linux-headers-6.5.0-kali3-amd64 (6.5.6-1kali1) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
Module 8188eu-1.0 for kernel 6.5.0-kali3-amd64 (x86_64).
Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

8188eu.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Module was not found within /lib/modules/6.5.0-kali3-amd64/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.
depmod...
Module realtek-rtl8188eus-5.3.9~git20230101.f8ead57 for kernel 6.5.0-kali3-amd64 (x86_64).
Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

8188eu.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/6.5.0-kali3-amd64/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.
depmod...
Module virtualbox-7.0.12 for kernel 6.5.0-kali3-amd64 (x86_64).
Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

vboxdrv.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/6.5.0-kali3-amd64/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

vboxnetadp.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/6.5.0-kali3-amd64/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

vboxnetflt.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/6.5.0-kali3-amd64/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.
depmod...
dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.5.0-kali3-amd64.
The kernel is built without module signing facility, modules won't be signed

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j4 KERNELRELEASE=6.5.0-kali3-amd64 -C /lib/modules/6.5.0-kali3-amd64/build M=/var/lib/dkms/8188eu/1.0/build.............
Cleaning build area...

8188eu.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/6.5.0-kali3-amd64/updates/dkms/
depmod...
The kernel is built without module signing facility, modules won't be signed

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' -j4 KVER=6.5.0-kali3-amd64 KSRC=/lib/modules/6.5.0-kali3-amd64/build..........................
Cleaning build area...

8188eu.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/6.5.0-kali3-amd64/updates/dkms/
depmod...
The kernel is built without module signing facility, modules won't be signed

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' -j4 KVER=6.5.0-kali3-amd64 KSRC=/lib/modules/6.5.0-kali3-amd64/build.................(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-kali3-amd64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8188eu/5.13.3/build/make.log for more information.
The kernel is built without module signing facility, modules won't be signed

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j4 KERNELRELEASE=6.5.0-kali3-amd64 -C /lib/modules/6.5.0-kali3-amd64/build M=/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.12/build.......
Cleaning build area...

vboxdrv.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/6.5.0-kali3-amd64/updates/dkms/

vboxnetadp.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/6.5.0-kali3-amd64/updates/dkms/

vboxnetflt.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/6.5.0-kali3-amd64/updates/dkms/
depmod...
dkms autoinstall on 6.5.0-kali3-amd64/x86_64 succeeded for 8188eu realtek-rtl8188eus virtualbox
dkms autoinstall on 6.5.0-kali3-amd64/x86_64 failed for rtl8188eu(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
dkms: autoinstall for kernel: 6.5.0-kali3-amd64 failed!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
Failed to process /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-headers-6.5.0-kali3-amd64.postinst line 11.
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.5.0-kali3-amd64 (--configure):
 installed linux-headers-6.5.0-kali3-amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-amd64:
 linux-headers-amd64 depends on linux-headers-6.5.0-kali3-amd64 (= 6.5.6-1kali1); however:
  Package linux-headers-6.5.0-kali3-amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-6.5.0-kali3-amd64
 linux-headers-6.5.0-kali3-amd64
 linux-headers-amd64
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I check module signing facility, allowed for both kernel(kali1 and kali3),
`/boot/config-6.5.0-kali1-amd64` and `/boot/config-6.5.0-kali3-amd64`

Modification:

```
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG=y
```

here are some additional info for mitigation:

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-6.5.0-kali1-amd64                               6.5.3-1kali1                              amd64        Linux 6.5 for 64-bit PCs
iF  linux-image-6.5.0-kali3-amd64                               6.5.6-1kali1                              amd64        Linux 6.5 for 64-bit PCs
ic  linux-image-amd64                                           6.5.6-1kali1                              amd64        Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-package)
```

```
dkms status                                      
8188eu/1.0, 6.5.0-kali1-amd64, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
8188eu/1.0, 6.5.0-kali3-amd64, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
lime-forensics/1.9.1-5, 6.5.0-kali1-amd64, x86_64: installed
realtek-rtl8188eus/5.3.9~git20230101.f8ead57, 6.5.0-kali1-amd64, x86_64: installed
realtek-rtl8188eus/5.3.9~git20230101.f8ead57, 6.5.0-kali3-amd64, x86_64: installed
rtl8188eu/4.1.4: added
rtl8188eu/5.13.3: added
virtualbox/7.0.12, 6.5.0-kali1-amd64, x86_64: installed
virtualbox/7.0.12, 6.5.0-kali3-amd64, x86_64: installed
```

I can boot successfully on both kernel,
I can do wifi hacking.